# C# method to insert to Teradata quickly

Tags: c#, asp.net, teradata

I'm trying to write a method in C# which when passed a System.Data.DataTable and destination database and table name, inserts the data.

I have this working well for SQL Server destinations, but for Teradata destinations the method I have come up with is incredibly slow by comparison (~70x time), which for some of the data my users will need to upload is unacceptable.

I'm posting both sets of code below, hoping someone can help me with a better method for Teradata please?

Teradata (using Teradata.Client.Provider library):

```
public static void UploadTDData(DataTable dtLogData, string destination)
        {

            // Get destination table structure without data
            var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} where 0 = 1", destination);
            using (TdDataAdapter insertAdapter = new TdDataAdapter(query, myTeradataConnection))
            {
                DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                insertAdapter.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow row in dtLogData.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                    newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
                    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }

                TdCommandBuilder builder = new TdCommandBuilder(insertAdapter);
                //No limit on batch size
                insertAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0;
                insertAdapter.Update(dt);
            }
        }
```

SQL Server:

```
public static void UploadData(DataTable dtLogData, string destination)
        {

                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(mySQLConnection))
                {                                         
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destination; 
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtLogData);
                }

        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a batch? https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/netfx/2011/04/how-to-specify-a-transaction-for-a-batch-update-with-tdcommandbuilder-and-tddataa

Comment: I might be missing your point here but the code I posted works pretty much the same way as the link you posted (schema is obtained from query and I loop the existing table rather than your example which adds two rows of individual values), could you be explicit about what I should change? (The time hog is insertAdapter.Update(dt), which in your example is adapter.Update(table))

Comment: It uses a transaction so rather than committing each row individually it kinda stores them to be done

Comment: I don't think that's what the transaction is doing there, how much data is processed at once is controlled by the batch size. It looks like the point of the demo is to identify the whole data load as one transaction, so you can choose to commit or rollback the whole lot rather than the final batch of x records, but this is relevant for after processing the data. I have tested this in my code but it actually makes it slightly slower

Comment: If you use a DataTable it will take a considerable time, pass a DataReader instead.